# Is DebugAdapterTracker supported in VS Code web extensions?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm calling registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory but createDebugAdapterTracker isn't getting called when starting a debug session. It works in a normal VSCode extension, but not a web extension. I can't find any documentation saying this is a limitation of web extensions. Is it?

I'm certain that the registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory call is happening as I see console output just before it. But no console output from in createDebugAdapterTracker, and none in the tracker's callbacks. I do see all this output when using a non-web extension.

```
console.log('registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory')
vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory('*', {
  createDebugAdapterTracker: (session: vscode.DebugSession): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.DebugAdapterTracker> => {
    console.log("createDebugAdapterTracker", session.id);
    return {
      onWillStartSession(): void {
        console.log(session.id, 'onWillStartSession');
      },
      onWillReceiveMessage(message: any): void {
        console.log(session.id, 'onWillReceiveMessage', message);
      },

etc.
```

I've tried using both "*" and "pwa-chome" (which is the debug session type I'm testing with).

I do see output from onDidStartDebugSession in both kinds of extensions.